# Round value from json

Tags: json, jasper-reports, expression

I'm creating a report using *iReport 5.6.0* and json as datasource.
In this datasource all values have a dot as decimal mark.

> 15.880005

Because this is a monetary value, I need to round it.

Using

```
#,##0.00 €
```

will print 15.880.005,00 €.
What I want is 15,88 €.

How do I display the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing like that because your value is of type `String` and not `double` so to apply the patter first you need to parse it to double.

Instead of directly using the field name first parse it to `double` by using the below code.

```
Double.valueOf($F{field_name})
```

Add null check if required.